# Update input value only if it equals to some array's current value in for loop

Tags: reactjs

I have an array

```
["a","b","c","d"]
```

And I have an input

```
        <input value={inputValue} onChange={(e) => onInputChangeHandler(e)}/>
```

I want onInputChangeHandler to check if the typed letter equals to the first element of the array, and if it equals then update the input with the typed letter, if it doesn't equal just do nothing. Then when user types another letter, I want onInputHanlder to check if the letter equals to second element of the array and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
const TestComponent = () => {
  const myArr = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState("");

  function onInputChangeHandler(e) {
    if (myArr[e.target.value.length - 1] === e.target.value.slice(-1)) {
      setInputValue(e.target.value);
    }
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <input value={inputValue} onChange={(e) => onInputChangeHandler(e)} />
    </div>
   );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to store the index you are on in the array.

You have written the if/else logic in words in your question so you should be able to write that up easily within onInputChangeHandler.

Once you have a variable like `letterIndex` you can start it at 0 and increment it each time onInputChangeHandler is called.

Assuming this exists in a React component this would go into the state of the component and operations would be done the same way you would handle tracking any other state.

Comment: I came up with `const [letterIndex, setLetterIndex] = useState(0)
    const onInputChange = (e) => {
        if(wordControl[letterIndex] == e.target.value) {
            
            setInputValue(e.target.value)
            setLetterIndex((prev) => prev+1)            
        }             
    }`
After the function is called for the first time everything is ok but next time it triggers, e.target.value is already "ab" and "ab" !== "b"

Answer (score 0):

All you need is `.startsWith()`. This is the implementation function:

```js
const onInputChangeHandler = userInput => {
  let arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
  if (arr.join('').startsWith(userInput)) {
    console.log('update the state');
  }else{
    console.log('func will be returned without state update');
  }
}

onInputChangeHandler('abc');
onInputChangeHandler('abv');
```

Comment: It does not work like that. Your code will always check if the letter user typed starts with 'a'

Comment: If a user types a letter in an input, the `userInput` will receive the whole string from starting and not just the entered letter. So it will be a match.